# Positive $p$-summing operators and disjoint $p$-summing operators

Tags: banach-spaces

In 1987, O. Blasco introduced the concept of positive $p$-summing operators as follows:

Let $X$ be a Banach lattice and $E$ be a Banach space. An operator $T:X\rightarrow E$ is positive $p$-summing if there exists a constant $C$ such that for any choice of finitely many positive vectors $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ in $X$, one has
$$(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\|Tx_{i}\|^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq C\sup_{x^{*}\in B_{X^{*}}}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\langle x^{*},x_{i}\rangle|^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

Obviously, every absolutely $p$-summing operator from a Banach lattice to a Banach space is positive $p$-summing. O. Blasco proved that the converse is not true in general.

If we replace the finitely many positve vectors $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ in $X$ in the definition of positive $p$-summing operators by finitely many pairwise disjoint vectors $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ in $X$, we can introduce the concept of disjoint $p$-summing operators. It is easy to see that an operator $T:X\rightarrow E$ is disjoint $p$-summing if and only if there exists a constant $C$ such that for all pairwise disjoint positive elements $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ in $X$, we have
$$(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\|Tx_{i}\|^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq C\sup_{x^{*}\in B_{X^{*}}}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\langle x^{*},x_{i}\rangle|^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

Hence, every positive $p$-summing operator is disjoint $p$-summing.

Question. Do positive $p$-summing operators and disjoint $p$-summing operators coincide?

Thank you!